# disabling hibernate: console log in spring @DataJpaTest

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, log4j, log4j2

I'm getting these logs, the first I know what enables it, the second I have no idea, it's always there. It doesn't seem to go through log4j. How do I disable the log line that begins with `Hibernate`?

```
DEBUG - insert into exceptions (created_on, last_modified_on, version, business_division_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) : hibernate.SQL 
Hibernate: insert into exceptions (created_on, last_modified_on, version, business_division_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I enabled the first via

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

I'm not sure if it matters but I've got H2 auto configured as the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second line seems like the old "log to `System.out`" Hibernate feature. Since it does not use a logging framework, you can not disable it through Log4j2/Spring Boot configuration.

You can however disable it by setting `hibernate.show_sql` to false in your Hibernate properties (cf. [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_sql_statement_logging)).

Since you are using Spring Boot, that option also appears as `spring.jpa.show-sql` Spring Boot properties (cf. [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.jpa.show-sql)).

**Edit:** To disable SQL statement logging you can also set the `showSql` property on the [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) annotation to `false`.

Comment: `spring.jpa.show-sql=false` doesn't seem to disable that. Also can't figure out a way to set `hibernate.show_sql`

Comment: The [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) annotation seems to have a `showSql` property that defaults to `true`. Try setting it to `false`.